# CLISP Lambda Calculus Div Implementation

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to implement a Division function with clisp Lambda Calc. style

I read from [this](http://jwodder.freeshell.org/lambda.html) site that lambda expression of a division is:

> Y (λgqab. LT a b (PAIR q a) (g (SUCC q) (SUB a b) b)) 0

These are TRUE and FALSE

```
(defvar TRUE #'(lambda(x)#'(lambda(y)x)))
(defvar FALSE #'(lambda(x)#'(lambda(y)y)))
```

These are conversion functions between Int and Church numbers

```
(defun church2int(numchurch)
    (funcall (funcall numchurch #'(lambda (x) (+ x 1))) 0)
)
(defun int2church(n)
    (cond
        ((= n 0) #'(lambda(f) #'(lambda(x)x)))
        (t #'(lambda(f) #'(lambda(x) (funcall f
            (funcall(funcall(int2church (- n 1))f)x))))))

)
```

This is my IF-THEN-ELSE Implementation

```
(defvar IF-THEN-ELSE
    #'(lambda(c)
        #'(lambda(x)
            #'(lambda(y)
                #'(lambda(acc1)
                    #'(lambda (acc2)
                        (funcall (funcall (funcall (funcall c x) y) acc1) acc2))))))
)
```

And this is my div implementation

```
(defvar division
    #'(lambda (g)
        #'(lambda (q)
            #'(lambda (a)
                #'(lambda (b)
                    (funcall (funcall (funcall (funcall (funcall IF-THEN-ELSE LT) a) b)
                        (funcall (funcall PAIR q)a))
                        (funcall (funcall g (funcall succ q)) (funcall (funcall sub a)b))
                    )))))

)
```

PAIR, SUCC and SUB functions work fine. I set my church numbers up like this

```
(set six (int2church 6))
(set two (int2church 2))
```

Then I do:

```
(setq D (funcall (funcall division six) two))
```

And I've got:

```
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (A)
  #'(LAMBDA (B)
     (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL IF-THEN-ELSE LT) A) B) (FUNCALL (FUNCALL PAR Q) A))
      (FUNCALL (FUNCALL G (FUNCALL SUCC Q)) (FUNCALL (FUNCALL SUB A) B))))>
```

For what I understand, this function return a Church Pair. If I try to get the first element
with a function FRST (FRST works ok) like this:

(funcall frst D)

I've got

```
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (B)
  (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL IF-THEN-ELSE LT) A) B) (FUNCALL (FUNCALL PAR Q) A))
   (FUNCALL (FUNCALL G (FUNCALL SUCC Q)) (FUNCALL (FUNCALL SUB A) B)))>
```

If I try to get the int value with Church2int (Church2int works OK) like this:

```
(church2int (funcall frst D))
```

I've got

```
*** - +:
       #<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (N)
         #'(LAMBDA (F)
            #'(LAMBDA (X)
               (FUNCALL (FUNCALL (FUNCALL N #'(LAMBDA (G) #'(LAMBDA (H) (FUNCALL H (FUNCALL G F))))) #'(LAMBDA (U) X)) (LAMBDA (U) U))))>
      is not a number
```

Where I expect to get 3

I think the problem is in DIVISION function, after the IF-THEN-ELSE, I tried to change it a little bit (I thought it was a nested parenthesis problem) but I got lots of errors.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your definition.

`DIVISION` does not use the **Y** combinator, but the original definition does.
This is important, because the `DIVISION` function expects a copy of itself in the `g`
parameter.

However, even if you added the **Y** invocation, your code would still not work
but go into an infinite loop instead. That's because Common Lisp, like most of today's languages, is a call-by-value language. All arguments are evaluated before a function is called. This means that you cannot define conditional functions as elegantly as the traditional lambda calculus semantics would allow.

Here's one way of doing church number division in Common Lisp. I've taken the liberty of introducing some syntax to make this a bit more readable.

```
;;;; -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
;;;; --- preamble, define lambda calculus language

(cl:in-package #:cl-user)

(defpackage #:lambda-calc
  ;; note: not using common-lisp package
  (:use)
  (:export #:λ #:call #:define))

;; (lambda-calc:λ (x y) body)
;;   ==> (cl:lambda (x) (cl:lambda (y) body))
(defmacro lambda-calc:λ ((arg &rest more-args) body-expr)
  (labels ((rec (args)
             (if (null args)
               body-expr
               `(lambda (,(car args))
                  (declare (ignorable ,(car args)))
                  ,(rec (cdr args))))))
    (rec (cons arg more-args))))

;; (lambda-calc:call f a b)
;;   ==> (cl:funcall (cl:funcall f a) b)
(defmacro lambda-calc:call (func &rest args)
  (labels ((rec (args)
             (if (null args)
               func
               `(funcall ,(rec (cdr args)) ,(car args)))))
    (rec (reverse args))))

;; Defines top-level lexical variables
(defmacro lambda-calc:define (name value)
  (let ((vname (gensym (princ-to-string name))))
    `(progn
       (defparameter ,vname nil)
       (define-symbol-macro ,name ,vname)
       (setf ,name
             (flet ((,vname () ,value))
               (,vname))))))

;; Syntax: {f a b}
;;   ==> (lambda-calc:call f a b)
;;   ==> (cl:funcall (cl:funcall f a) b)
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (set-macro-character #\{
                       (lambda (stream char)
                         (declare (ignore char))
                         `(lambda-calc:call
                            ,@(read-delimited-list #\} stream t))))
  (set-macro-character #\} (get-macro-character #\))))

;;;; --- end of preamble, fun starts here

(in-package #:lambda-calc)

;; booleans
(define TRUE
  (λ (x y) x))
(define FALSE
  (λ (x y) y))
(define NOT
  (λ (bool) {bool FALSE TRUE}))

;; numbers
(define ZERO
  (λ (f x) x))
(define SUCC
  (λ (n f x) {f {n f x}}))
(define PLUS
  (λ (m n) {m SUCC n}))
(define PRED
  (λ (n f x)
    {n (λ (g h) {h {g f}})
       (λ (u) x)
       (λ (u) u)}))
(define SUB
  (λ (m n) {n PRED m}))

(define ISZERO
  (λ (n) {n (λ (x) FALSE) TRUE}))
(define <=
  (λ (m n) {ISZERO {SUB m n}}))
(define <
  (λ (m n) {NOT {<= n m}}))

(define ONE   {SUCC ZERO})
(define TWO   {SUCC ONE})
(define THREE {SUCC TWO})
(define FOUR  {SUCC THREE})
(define FIVE  {SUCC FOUR})
(define SIX   {SUCC FIVE})
(define SEVEN {SUCC SIX})
(define EIGHT {SUCC SEVEN})
(define NINE  {SUCC EIGHT})
(define TEN   {SUCC NINE})

;; combinators
(define Y
  (λ (f)
    {(λ (rec arg) {f {rec rec} arg})
     (λ (rec arg) {f {rec rec} arg})}))

(define IF
  (λ (condition if-true if-false)
    {{condition if-true if-false} condition}))

;; pairs
(define PAIR
  (λ (x y select) {select x y}))
(define FIRST
  (λ (pair) {pair TRUE}))
(define SECOND
  (λ (pair) {pair FALSE}))

;; conversion from/to lisp integers
(cl:defun int-to-church (number)
  (cl:if (cl:zerop number)
    zero
    {succ (int-to-church (cl:1- number))}))
(cl:defun church-to-int (church-number)
  {church-number #'cl:1+ 0})

;; what we're all here for
(define DIVISION
  {Y (λ (recurse q a b)
       {IF {< a b}
           (λ (c) {PAIR q a})
           (λ (c) {recurse {SUCC q} {SUB a b} b})})
     ZERO})
```

If you put this into a file, you can do:

```
[1]> (load "lambdacalc.lisp")
;; Loading file lambdacalc.lisp ...
;; Loaded file lambdacalc.lisp
T
[2]> (in-package :lambda-calc)
#<PACKAGE LAMBDA-CALC>
LAMBDA-CALC[3]> (church-to-int {FIRST {DIVISION TEN FIVE}})
2
LAMBDA-CALC[4]> (church-to-int {SECOND {DIVISION TEN FIVE}})
0
LAMBDA-CALC[5]> (church-to-int {FIRST {DIVISION TEN FOUR}})
2
LAMBDA-CALC[6]> (church-to-int {SECOND {DIVISION TEN FOUR}})
2
```